# Enable google cloud storage with free

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to host Php Site Using Cloud API.
Could some one please help me to enable Google Cloud Storage with Free.

I have been referring the few Google official API Docs(https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) but it asking for enable billable.

How can I proceed without enable billable.

Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about billing.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid billing do not use Cloud SQL.  To store data without using Cloud SQL do not use PHP at present.  Use the Datastore instead with Python, Java or Go.